# Variable not incrementing inside multiple loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, nested-loops

This issue has me stumped.  I have a variable I am sharing in a loop and it is not incrementing.

The variable in question is elrObject.currentLocation.  There are two ways to increment it - either if the XML element is empty or if it's not.

Here is the code:

```
if (reader.Name == "Cell")
{  
    if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
    {       
        Response.Write("i ran<br>");
        elrObject.currentLocation++;
    }       
    else
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {           
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {                                           
                //labels
                if (elrObject.currentLocation >= elrObject.index && elrObject.currentLocation <= elrObject.index + elrObject.colSpan)
                    Response.Write("i ran again<br>");

                Response.Write(elrObject.currentLocation + "<br>");
                elrObject.currentLocation++;

            }
            if (reader.Name == "Cell")
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is:
0
1
2
3
5

The number 4 is when the XML element is empty and the top loop runs.  I am incrementing the variable but it won't show me number 4, it skips it entirely and goes to 5.  I am sure the upper loop is running properly and before the lower one because the following also runs:

I ran
I ran again
This confirms the upper loop is running before the lower one....yet the number 4 is skipping itself!  I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not *supposed* to show number 4. You don't have a

```
Response.Write(elrObject.currentLocation + "<br>");
```

in the

```
if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
```

block.

Comment: agree, that would be the problem.

Comment: But on the next iteration of (reader.Name == "Cell"), when it enters the bottom loop, shouldn't it show it there?  After all, the response.write is before the increment.

Comment: @johnhannigan You're incrementing it by: `elrObject.currentLocation++;` in the first block.

Comment: Right, I also increment it in the second block (at the end).  But my problem here is that the second block never shows this variable as 4 even though it is shared between the loops.  After it is incremented to 4, the next time the loop runs it goes to block 2 and it should be at 4 at that point.

Comment: @johnhannigan You wrote: `After it is incremented to 4, the next time the loop runs it goes to block 2` - That's your mistake. It really goes to block 1.

Comment: So it's actually going to block 1 twice?  It only shows "i ran" once.  i know your right and im failing to see something basic here but i cant put my finger on it

Comment: @johnhannigan I think CodesInChaos's idea is a good one. Set a breakpoint at the first line, and when it breaks - quickly `Step Over` (-F10) and right-click on `currentLocation` and "Add watch" - and see its value as you `F10` through the code.

Comment: @johnhannigan No. It's only going there once. It enters **block-2** as `3`, and is printed. Then is incremented to `4` and leaves. Then enters **block-1** as `4`, and is _not_ printed, then is incremented to `5` and leaves. Then enters **block-2** as `5` and is printed.

Comment: Oh wow, NOW I see it.  I can't believe the time and energy wasted into something so simple.  Thanks for being patient.